# jquery cycle plugin responds badly

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I have implemented a slideshow using jquery cycle plugin  :  the problem with the slideshow is that it displays first image away from its container and after that it shows all slideshow images correctly, The first image takes time to load and until then it remains in rightest corner of my website which makes my website look dirty... Please do help

Link is [here](http://tripmaker.co/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below css

```
.slideshow img{top:0; left:0; position:absolute; display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS positioning property for your `.slideshow {` elements

Comment: ya it was helpful but you just failled to explain that i have to position images of slideshow as you can inspect on runtime my slideshow class is already positioned as relative ,,,, ny ways thanks for help